# After knitting Rmd, pdf file does not include figures from chunks but there are in the figure folder

Tags: r, knitr, figure

I am knitting a pdf file from `Rmd.`. My working dir includes the `.Rmd` file and pdf output. Knitr sends all figures to the `figure` folder because I set the figure path to `fig.path <- "figure/"`. But when I knit the pdf file, it gives me an error: `` ! LaTeX Error: File `figure/figure-1' not found. `` although all figures are in the `figure` folder. Something is wrong with my directories but I cannot figure out what exactly.

Here is my setting:

```
---
title: "Paper"
subtitle: "\\textsc{Online Paper}"
df_print: paged
author: "Anonymous"
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: flafter
    includes:
    # in_header: Helper/header.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
  link-citations: yes
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
# bibliography: Helper/bibtex.bib
biblio-style: apa6
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
urlcolor: blue
---
```

Comment: How do you knit the document (from the command line or using the button in RStudio)? Can you provide a minimal example that includes only the settings required to reproduce the issue and one plot, e.g. `plot(1)`?